# How to split mathematical expression on components in java?

Tags: java, math

I have some issue about split mathematical expression.

I want to split every number, operator and parentheses, and send them to an array, this is my code for different case:

```
String infix = "-(1/10)^(-2)-(-2)^(5)-2-3+1^(-2)";

//List<String>    tokenList = Arrays.asList(infix.split("(?<=[+*/()!^-])|(?=[+*/()!^-])"));
//List<String>    tokenList = Arrays.asList(infix.split("(?=[-+*/()])|(?<=[^-+*/][-+*/])|(?<=[()])"));
//List<String>     tokenList = Arrays.asList(infix.split("((?<=\\^)|(?=\\^))"));
List<String>     tokenList = Arrays.asList(infix.split("((?<=[+*/()!])|(?=[+*/()!]))|((?<=\\^)|(?=\\^))|([0-9]+(?<=[-])|(?=[-]))"));
```

i can't separate it. I often got wrong  expression

[1, 10, /, -2, ^, -2, 5, -2, -3, ^, 1, -2, ^, +, -, -]

My program can't divide minus sign.
if have `-1-1` my program divide it like  [-1,-1].
Please, help me solve this issue.

Comment: Do you need this to be done using regex? Usually this would be solved using a basic char-by-char parser which would give you the ability to persist context/state and let you more easily handle whether you're inside brackets, after a minus sign, etc.

Comment: Hi, Aaron. I need do it any way. Also, if you know some easier example, please, send link.

Comment: I don't have any sample specific to your question, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634380/how-can-i-split-string-by-a-special-character-and-ignore-everything-inside-paren/54634710#54634710)'s another question where OP started with regex and I answered with "better use a basic parser". In this answer I maintain a nestingLevel variable which lets me know if I'm inside brackets or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Aaron. The solution could be based on FSM (finite state machine). Essentially, you have a string expression, and you are starting parsing. Also, consider there's a temporary string variable that is empty for now.
When you read the first char, you go and write it to the variable and decide, what it is: in this example, it could be a number, an operator, or a space. You jump to a special state (which should also be stored somewhere). Then you read the next char in the expression, and now you have the history (the current state and the previously read chars). Here you can decide if the token is ended or not, and depending on that you can jump to another state.

For example, you read `"1"`. You know, that, for instance, it could be a number of any length. You persist `"1"` in a variable and read the next char. If there's another digit, you could be sure that there's still the same number. If there's a space, or another operator, you push the `"1"` from the first step to a list of tokens or wherever, clear the string, and persist the next character in it.

Quite often it could be implemented using a `switch-case` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I found answers on my issue ( code below). It's very easier way to solve this problem.

```
List<String>     tokenList = Arrays.asList(infix.split(
        "((?<=\\^)|(?=\\^))|((?<=\\s[-+]\\s)" +
        "|(?=\\s[-+]\\s))|((?<=[()])|(?=[()]))" +
        "|((?<=[*/])|(?=[*/]))" +
        "|((?<=\\s[*/]\\s))"));
```